# Log4net cannot access the passed properties in the conversion pattern

Tags: c#, logging, windows-7, log4net

I have Log4net writing to a RollingFileAppender in all my development and production systems, and it has been doing so for several release versions. I recently updated (i.e., removed and reinstalled) the application version installed on a salesperson's laptop and now Log4net aborts each Write operation when it encounters a `%property{propname}` conversion pattern. Everything in the conversion pattern before the first `%property` item (like `%date` or`%message`) will log correctly for that call, but nothing after it.

The properties are passed using the ThreadContext Stack, basically like this:

```
using (ThreadContext.Stacks["EventID"].Push(eventIDstr))
using (ThreadContext.Stacks["CategoryID"].Push(categoryIDstr))
{
    log.Debug(message, exception);
}
```

I saw this same behavior happen recently when I was building up a new development machine and I thought it was resolved by one of the Windows updates or other package installs that I did afterward, but I really have no concrete clues to what solved it other than knowing it had nothing to do with my code or configuration file (which all remained unchanged). What DLL or other file/assembly could be the culprit?

Comment: Have you tried [enabling log4net internal logging](https://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx/) and looking at the output?

Comment: I have now....
The only reported error is this: `ERROR [RollingFileAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Failed in DoAppend
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. That is followed by the exception stack trace up from log4net.Core.LoggingEvent.get_UserName().`
Six log entries were written, all truncated at the first `%property` item. I don't see that as much help since logging was working before the app update.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Installing .NET Framework 4.5 did the trick. With only Framework 4.0, it doesn't work.